# Function that returns two functions

Tags: python, function

The function menu5 returns a message to the user. I would like at the same time that the user called this function, that it called another similar function, that sent message to another person.
Here is the code:

```
def menu5(self, message=None, match=None, to=None):
    # Retransfer the requester's phone
    number = message.getFrom()
    # Cut after the @
    number = number.split('@')
    # Separate only the number
    number = number[0]
    # Delete the 55
    number = number[2:13]
    # Person who will receive the message
    toSend = '5527999999999@s.whatsapp.net'       

    # Function call to be triggered
    self.operator(msg=number, op=toSend)

    return textMessageProtocolEntity(txtMenu5, to=message.getFrom())

def operator(self, to=None, msg=None, op=None):
    return TextMessageProtocolEntity(msg, to=op)
```

Comment: Do you have a specific question?

Comment: Yes, I would like that when the user calls the function menu5(), at the same time executes the function operator() using the parameters obtained in menu5()

Comment: That's a statement, not a question. Did you try it? What specific thing isn't working?

Comment: When I tried it, it only executed the return from the menu5()

Comment: I would like him to do the 2 returns

Comment: Basically I have to return to the user and at the same time, cascade, call a function that tells another user.

Answer (score 0):

If you want the return value of some function, you need to explicitly store it:

```
def menu5(self, message=None, match=None, to=None):
    # ...  

    # Function call to be triggered
    txtmsg = self.operator(msg=number, op=toSend)

    return TextMessageProtocolEntity(txtMenu5, to=message.getFrom()), txtmsg
```

The function `menu5` now returns a two-element tuple with two `TextMessageProtocolEntity`s in it. Note that your original code was always calling `self.operator`, as expected - it just wasn't doing anything with the return value.

Comment: I had even tried it that way, but there I get a mistake: AttributeError: 'tuple' object has no attribute 'getTag'

Comment: That's because you're trying to access that attribute on the tuple instead of the things inside it. If you wanted to access attributes or methods on the `TextMessageProtocolEntity`, you would need to extract them out the returned tuple. Take a look at [this](https://en.wikibooks.org/wiki/Python_Programming/Tuples).